# Interrupt execution of v8 script inside native function

Tags: c++, v8, spidermonkey

I use v8 and spidermonkey from C++ programs. In spidermonkey it is easy to stop the execution, you just return FALSE in any of native methods you implemented in C++.
But I fail to see how to do the same thing in v8.

```
Handle<Value> enough(const v8::Arguments& a) {
    // want to tell v8, that execution is not needed to continue.
    return v8::Undefined();
}
```

maybe return something specific, or set some variable, or call v8 function, or send a message, or throw and exception, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what do you mean by "interrupt" in this case.. But I will give it a shot with my answer:

You can either return a value from your C++ function early on (`return v8::False()`) to skip execution of other code inside the same function or throw a JavaScript exception with `v8::ThrowException(...)`.

And you can use the `v8::V8::TerminateExecution()`. This will terminate the execution in current isolate/thread. The way v8 does that is by throwing an uncatchable exception (in JavaScript land). You can still use the `v8::TryCatch` to handle the termination from your C++ code.

Comment: V8::TerminateExecution() is what I was looking for! Thank you. Other suggestions are also very helpful! I wish you coudl find this kind of information easily in non-existing documentation.